# "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" when using max function

Tags: python

Im working with a data set and Im trying to find the highest amount of cases in a country depending on the year, so I reduced my dictionary to a list which only has the cases of that specific year and country, and I want to find from that list the highest number of cases,
the output list looks something like this:
[500, 100, 500, 15000, 18000, 100, 11000, '-1', 200, 2500, '-1', '-1', '-1', 100, '-1', 100, 26000, 100, 1400, '-1',] so in this case I would like to use the max function to get the highest value which in this case would be 26000 but its giving me this error saying: "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"  like where am I using a string?

```
def find_most_infected_country(year : int) -> Dict[str,any]:
    
    
    
    new_list = []
    
    for item in dataset:
        dictionary = dict()
        for key in item:
            if item.get(key) == "Global": #get rid of the key global
                break
            else:
                if key == str(year): # add to the list everything else
                    new_list.append(item[key])
    
    print(new_list)
    
    
    
    
    biggest_number = max(new_list)

    
    index_highest_number = empty_list.index(highest_number)

    
    highest_country = dataset[index_highest_number]
 
    
    dictionary["country"] = highest_country["country"]
    dictionary["year"] = year
    dictionary["cases"] = max(new_list)
    
    return dictionary

find_most_infected_country(1991)
```

Comment: the minus 1 looks like a string to me. Without the content of `dataset`, hard to say anyway

Comment: omg youre totally right I missed that out! Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to change all the -1 from a list to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look, it seems that the strings are the '-1' . However, this does not make sense to me that there are -1 cases ... It's possible that your data is corrupted in some way, which leads to what you're seeing here.
I guess that if you want a simple solution, just change the list like :

```py
lst = [ int(item) for item in lst]
```

I guess that if the '-1' are the only problem, this should also work:

```py
lst = [item for item in lst if item !='-1']
```

Or even this should be enough, to filter all the non int values

```py
lst  = [item for item in lst if isinstance(item,int)]
```

Then you can apply max to the modified list

Comment: just change the name lst to new_list or the opposite

Comment: lst was just a random name I chose for a list

Comment: but with your code it tells me that the name has been referenced before the assigment

Comment: new_list = [ int(item) for item in new_list]

Comment: How do I make it so that it doesnt give me the local variable 'new_list' referenced before assignment error?

Comment: You can only filter the list after you created it

Comment: hence after the for loop

Comment: There it is surely defined, and contains all the values

Comment: Yeah youre right, it worked after I placed it after the for loop

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You could use `max(map(int,new_list))` to ensure that the '-1' strings are processed as integers.

But, really, you should store them as actual integers in the list.  Mixed type list only complicate the code that uses them: `new_list.append(int(item[key]))`